# After upgrading from Grails 2 to Grails 3 I can no longer access the Grails console

Tags: grails, console

| Grails Version: 3.0.17
| Groovy Version: 2.4.5
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_112

I can no longer access the Grails console after upgrading.

> Error: Could not find or load main class grails.ui.console.GrailsSwingConsole

UPDATE:

I read the instructions from [Grails console](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/sheehan/console/) and added the following lines but unfortunately I still receive the same error.

```
# application.groovy
grails.resources.pattern = '/**'

# build.gradle
runtime 'org.grails.plugins:grails-console:2.1.1'
```

Comment: Do you have the console dependency in your `build.gradle` file? `console "org.grails:grails-console"`

Comment: Yes. console "org.grails:grails-console" is in my build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being my fault. I moved the database connection settings to an external config.groovy. Once I added them back to the config.yml everything worked!